# Ways to check LLM output and retry if incorrect but return output if correct?

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I'm giving an LLM 37 categories and asking it to label pieces of text with the categories that apply to it (likely multiple for each text). I ask it to output its response as a markdown table.

Problem: the LLM doesn't always return answers for all the categories.

I want to check if all the categories have been returned, if they have, finish. If they haven't, ask it to classify the categories it forgot about (or, if that's too complicated, ask it to do it again).

I've thought about a `RouterChain` but am not sure how to handle the default chain. `SequentialChain` also confuses me since you cannot account for different actions based on Yes/No answer from 'does this contain all the classes?'

```py
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

chat = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name='gpt-4')

survey_response = 'example response'
classes = ['class 1', 'class 2', 'class 3', ...]

template_string = """Here is a response from a survey question. I am performing
thematic analysis on it and wish to classify it into one of a list of pre-defined
classes.

Response:
####{response}####

Please output whether the response falls under any of these categories.

Classes:
####{classes}####

Output should be formatted as a table with 4 columns: 1) class, 2) is_member
 1/0 depending on if the response is a member of the class), 3) confidence_score 
 (a confidence interval for whether the response does fit into that class, 
 use low (0-20%), medium (50%-80%) and high (80%+), 4) exerpt (excerpt from the 
 response that supports the classification).
"""

prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template_string)

input_message = prompt_template.format_messages(
    response=survey_response,
    classes=classes
)
llm_response = chat(input_message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your situation, you can write a Python function that will verify if the LLM has categorized the text into all the provided categories and, if not, either re-prompts the LLM or handles the missing categories accordingly. basically in two steps.

1. **Parse the LLM Output**
   Extract the categories mentioned in the LLM output and compare them with the original list of categories.
2. **Reprompt Missing Categories**
   If any categories are missing, you can create a new prompt containing only the missing categories and ask the LLM to categorize them.

Suggesting a sample implementation code:

```
import re

def parse_markdown_table(md_table):
    # Assuming the table format is consistent as per the given structure
    lines = md_table.strip().split("\n")
    data_lines = lines[1:]  # Ignoring header in case you have
    
    parsed_data = []
    for line in data_lines:
        # Extracting data from markdown table rows (just my suggestion but take care in yur style with regx)
        match = re.match(r'\| ?([^|]+) ?\| ?(\d) ?\| ?([^|]+) ?\| ?([^|]+) ?\|', line)
        if match:
            class_name, is_member, confidence_score, excerpt = match.groups()
            if int(is_member):
                parsed_data.append({
                    'class': class_name.strip(),
                    'is_member': is_member.strip(),
                    'confidence_score': confidence_score.strip(),
                    'excerpt': excerpt.strip()
                })
    return parsed_data

def categorize_text(chat, prompt_template, survey_response, classes):
    missing_classes = set(classes)
    all_responses = []
    
    while missing_classes:
        input_message = prompt_template.format_messages(response=survey_response, classes=list(missing_classes))
        llm_response_raw = chat(input_message)  # Assuming llm_response is a markdown table as a string
        
        llm_response = parse_markdown_table(llm_response_raw)  # Parsing the markdown table
        returned_classes = {category['class'] for category in llm_response}
        
        all_responses.extend(llm_response)
        missing_classes -= returned_classes
    
    return all_responses

# Usage of the function
final_response = categorize_text(chat, prompt_template, survey_response, classes)
```

This function keeps reprompting the LLM for the missing classes until all classes have been categorized. In this implementation, the `parse_markdown_table` function utilizes regular expressions to extract relevant information from each row of the markdown table in `llm_response`. This data is then used to find out which classes were identified by the LLM, and that information is utilized in the subsequent loop iteration to figure out which classes still need to be identified. Note that the regular expression for parsing the markdown is my provisional suggestion and you can modify this according to your actual data.

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide some code to back up your answer? Also, is this the recommended LangChain way to do it?

Comment: Regarding LangChain, there is no explicitly "recommended" way for such a specific scenario mentioned in the official documentation, as it usually depends on your unique requirements and constraints. However, handling dynamic decisions like this is generally more about logic control and less about the specifics of a library, so while the library provides the tools to interact with the LLM, the way you decide to handle missing categories is mostly up to your project’s specific needs and your preferences.

Comment: Provided the code template for my solution in my message also

Comment: thanks for adding the code. Hmm, I find it odd that this behaviour is not included. They include ways to evaluate LLMs and parse output. This seems like an extension of parsing output, just checking if it's correct. I don't think this is going to work `returned_classes = {category['class'] for category in llm_response}` you'll need to parse the output markdown table. But we're mostly there.

Comment: You're correct @codeananda. I left out the code snippet which should parse the markdown table in the LLM response. But here is my provisional suggestion to parse the markdown table to extract and utilize the categorized classes. Implementing a function like parse_markdown_table using regular expressions can help extract the necessary data from the markdown formatted response. This parsed data will then be used to determine which classes have been identified by the LLM and which ones are missing, enabling iteration until all classes are covered. Therefore find my updated response.